# On selecting shortcode generate selected shortcode table inside page editor worrdpress

Tags: php, shortcode

i want to create a different different shortcode while choose particular shortcode relative table is show on page editor for example when user choose [some_random_code_sc] that shortcode
then relative table is

```
<div class="span3 column basic-column">
                    <div class="column-header">
                        <h4>Basic</h4>
                        <h2>$4.99</h2>
                    </div>
                    <div class="table-content">
                        <ul>
                            <li class="white-row">Per month</li>
                            <li>5 GB storage</li>
                            <li class="white-row">Enhanced security</li>
                            <li>8 Databases</li>
                            <li class="white-row">2 Users License</li>
                            <li>Ads-free</li>
                            <li class="white-row">Moderation tools</li>
                            <li>30 day trial</li>
                            <li class="white-row"><a href="#" class="signup-btn standard-column">Sign up</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

while choosing [some_random_code_sr] it show relative table

```
<div class="span3 column highlight-column">
                    <div class="column-header">
                        <h4>Standard</h4>
                        <h2>$5.99</h2>
                    </div>
                    <div class="table-content">
                        <ul>
                            <li class="white-row">Per month</li>
                            <li>5 GB storage</li>
                            <li class="white-row">Enhanced security</li>
                            <li>8 Databases</li>
                            <li class="white-row">2 Users License</li>
                            <li>Ads-free</li>
                            <li class="white-row">Moderation tools</li>
                            <li>30 day trial</li>
                            <li class="white-row"><a href="#" class="signup-btn standard-column">Sign up</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

all selective table shows on wordpress page editor can anyone suggest me what should do to create table in editor using shortcode.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't the way shortcode works. When you use shortcode it isn't processed in the editor, it is processed when someone views the page.

It sounds like what you really want is to add a custom button to TinyMCE and from there the user can select a table template (or whatever) that gets insert into the editor.

Here are some good resources for this:

[TinyMCE Custom Button in the WordPress codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/TinyMCE_Custom_Buttons)

[A tutorial from tutplus on creating the button](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/guide-to-creating-your-own-wordpress-editor-buttons--wp-30182)